# aws dynamodb many-to-many mapping exceeding adjacent list limit

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I had a dynamodb schema which looks quite similar to the one described in aws doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

PK = invoice-id, SK = bill-id

Here I have an invoice with more than 10000+ bills which exceeds the item limit 400k. I use an ImmutableSet for holding bills(connected nodes) which helps do deduplication.

What's the best way to work around this limit? If I want to keep latest ~100 bills in an invoice, is it possible to implement this at very minimal effort?

Currently due to the item limit, db stopped writing any bill data for the invoice. I tried setting ttl for bills however in the invoice entry it doesn't go off.

Comment: did you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html

Comment: probably a bad design but I am storing some "hot" data in the same table with predefined "cold" data, i think it will eventually hit limit of the db, need to address it in application layer.